# where should this code go? change word on nav bar when session active

Tags: php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_PILOT_ID'])) {
    echo "<a href=\"index.php?p=members\">Members Area</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href=\"index.php?p=login\">Login</a>";
}
?>
```

I need to put this code on my nav bar but everytime i do it just fails. Its so that if there is no session is will say login and go to login page. If there is a session it will say members area and take you to that page.

Here is the bit of coding where i want it to go in my nav bar:

```
<div id="MMMenuContainer0703235014_2">
<div id="MMMenu0703235014_2" onMouseOut="MM_menuStartTimeout(60);" onMouseOver="MM_menuResetTimeout();"><a href="index.php?p=join" id="MMMenu0703235014_2_Item_0" class="MMMIFVStyleMMMenu0703235014_2" onMouseOver="MM_menuOverMenuItem('MMMenu0703235014_2');">Join</a><a href="index.php?p=login" id="MMMenu0703235014_2_Item_1" class="MMMIVStyleMMMenu0703235014_2" onMouseOver="MM_menuOverMenuItem('MMMenu0703235014_2');">Members Area</a><a href="/forumilkley" target="_blank" id="MMMenu0703235014_2_Item_2" class="MMMIVStyleMMMenu0703235014_2" onMouseOver="MM_menuOverMenuItem('MMMenu0703235014_2');">Forum</a></div>
```

That is a big chunk of the relevant section.. more specifically need it to be here;

```
<a href="index.php?p=login" id="MMMenu0703235014_2_Item_1" class="MMMIVStyleMMMenu0703235014_2" onMouseOver="MM_menuOverMenuItem('MMMenu0703235014_2');">Members Area</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your link into a variable instead of echoing it, and then echo that link.

Try this.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_PILOT_ID'])) {
    $link = '<a href="index.php?p=login" id="MMMenu0703235014_2_Item_1" class="MMMIVStyleMMMenu0703235014_2" onMouseOver="MM_menuOverMenuItem(\'MMMenu0703235014_2\');">Members Area</a>';

} else {
    $link = "<a href=\"index.php?p=login\">Login</a>";
}
?>
<div id="MMMenu0703235014_2" onMouseOut="MM_menuStartTimeout(60);" onMouseOver="MM_menuResetTimeout();"><a href="index.php?p=join" id="MMMenu0703235014_2_Item_0" class="MMMIFVStyleMMMenu0703235014_2" onMouseOver="MM_menuOverMenuItem('MMMenu0703235014_2');">Join</a><?php echo $link; ?><a href="/forumilkley" target="_blank" id="MMMenu0703235014_2_Item_2" class="MMMIVStyleMMMenu0703235014_2" onMouseOver="MM_menuOverMenuItem('MMMenu0703235014_2');">Forum</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Its working as it should now.